# Preparing a lecture on free probability

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I am required to prepare a 1 hr long lecture on interesting topic(s) in free probability theory. My audience is supposed to be thorough with classical probability and statistics, without any prior knowledge on free probability. In fact, I will be sort of introducing free probability to them.

Now, the rules are as follows:

1) I should not give a very technical talk. The lecture should invite people into free probability, not scare them away.

2) I should not give detailed proofs, and if required, only sketches.

3) I should highlight connections between free probability with different branches of mathematics, physics, etc.

Any suggestion is welcome.

EDIT: My idea is as follows: First I will give the abstract operator theoretic definition, and then mention that in such an abstract setting, distributions do not really make sense. There is no distribution function. So we define distribution in a roundabout way: borrowing from physics, we define a linear functional, a trace, based on which we talk about distribution. We then define free random variables using the conventional lattice theory (existence of Mobius function) and zero cumulants. Then I will talk about free Gaussian distribution.

So I can introduce the subject, but I am looking for connections, examples and applications. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You mean the $C*$ algebra notion?  I think it's going to be technical no matter what.   The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_probability) offers some references.

Comment: Yes, but not in the Voiculescu way. My focus will be on random variables from the start.

Comment: I think I am the kind of person in your intended audience -  familiar with "classical probability and statistics" but I had never heard of free probability. So, if you need a guinea pig or a practice audience member I could listen :)